# Vim <leader> command works, but beeps error sound and moves the cursor

Tags: vim, macvim, beep

I have the following configuration in my `.vimrc` in OSX under MacVim.

```
let mapleader = ','
nnoremap <leader>af :Autoformat<CR>         " autoformat document
nnoremap <leader>ig :IndentGuidesToggle<CR> " indent guides toggle
nnoremap <leader>nt :NERDTreeToggle<CR>     " nerd tree toggle
nnoremap <leader>tb :TagbarToggle<CR>       " tagbar toggle
```

The commands work fine, but when I use them, the terminal beeps the sound for error and the cursor moves position about 4 lines.
This happens both when using Vim in iTerm2 and in GVim.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not put comments on the same line as your mappings as the comments will be executed.

```
let mapleader = ','
" autoformat document
nnoremap <leader>af :Autoformat<CR>
" indent guides toggle
nnoremap <leader>ig :IndentGuidesToggle<CR>
" nerd tree toggle
nnoremap <leader>nt :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <leader>tb :TagbarToggle<CR>
```

You may want to look at [idiomatic-vimrc](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc/blob/master/idiomatic-vimrc.vim) for basic do's and don't's for your `vimrc`.